# Adding a view inside a view

Tags: android, view, android-framelayout

I am trying to make a music player and I am stuck at this problem for about a day.

So what I am doing is that I am following a tutorial. In that we use a class called MediaController which is used to control ( like play/pause, progress bar  etc) your media.

Now what I am doing is trying  to do the same thing myself. That is , I am

1. I am sending a view ( in this case a list view ), to a class which will programmatically
2. add a frame layout ( that is what I saw in android source ) to this view
3. the frame layout uses a xml previously made called as  media_controller.

Here is some code.

```
public void anchorToView(View view){
    mainView = view;
    view.addOnLayoutChangeListener(layoutChangeListener);

     frameParams = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
    );

    removeAllViews();
    View v = makeControllerView();
}

private OnLayoutChangeListener layoutChangeListener = new OnLayoutChangeListener() {

    @Override
    public void onLayoutChange(View v, int left, int top, int right, int bottom, int oldLeft, int oldTop, int oldRight,
            int oldBottom) {
    }
};

private View vDemo;
private ImageButton pauseButton;

public View makeControllerView(){
    LayoutInflater inflater=  (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService
            (Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    vDemo = inflater.inflate(R.layout.media_controller, null);

    pauseButton = (ImageButton) vDemo.findViewById(R.id.pause);

    return vDemo;
}
```

Comment: So what is the problem?

Comment: nothing extra ( i mean the view that i make other thatn list view ) is shown.

Answer (score 0):

You make your controller view, but never add it to the parent view after calling removeAllViews(). You need to do something like this:

```
mainView.addView(v); // V being your controller view returned from makeControllerView()
```

Comment: I tried that actually there is no method for view to add view.

Comment: Although I am still looking for a better answer. But I have got a clue from Devsil's answer. That is using view group. the addView method is only available for viewgroup class..Hence using that. But still waiting for better answer.

Comment: If you know what type of view group (if it is one) that your mainView is (LinearLayout, RelativeLayout,FrameLayout, ect) you can cast that view to the appropriate view. like this  ((Linearlayout)mainView).addView(v);

Comment: But I will be using this method from different activities with different views. Hence view group.

Comment: well casting to a ViewGroup and adding the view would work, LinearLayout , RelativeLayout, FrameLayout, etc, all extend from ViewGroup.

Comment: but how will i know which view is it. I am going to use that class for different type of views.